# Are there any disadvantages of using libsodiums helpers for en-/decoding/comparision instead of the native ones?

Tags: side-channel-attack, timing-attack, libsodium

Libsodium has some [helpers](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/helpers/index.html), which allow [hexdecimal decoding](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/03-utilities-helpers.md#bin2hex), encoding and also constant-time string comparison.
So if you use the php binding `libsodium-php` you obviously also have the native php implementation of [`bin2hex`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) and [`hex2bin`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php). The libsodium replacements were introduced because the native implementations [are not timing-resistent](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91979/php-bin2hex-vulnerable-to-timing-attack). So for sensitive data this should be used.

But if you have a library/project where you use libsodium anyway are there any disadvantages of using libsodiums functions even in places where this would not be necessary?
I mean one advantage clearly would that you can prevent to forget to use these timing-save implementations in cases where it is important if you just use it everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Functions often become timing resistant by not using short circuit evaluation. There is conceivably a small performance price to be paid by not using short circuit evaluation.

In reality, this is probably not a bottleneck or serious concern. Edit: It also might be possible that libsodiums function is faster anyways.

I would have commented with this, but I don't have enough rep to comment. There may be more to consider.

Comment: "It also might be possible that libsodiums function is faster anyways." - Indeed I also thought so, because libsodium (also) uses a native C implementation, which is generally quite fast.

Comment: @rugk, if you call it from a higher level language, you go through the bindings which may slow it down. Plus the PHP's internal implementation is in C anyway. Bottom line: speed can go either way, benchmark if you care.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage is: You can be quite confident that, if every other bit of the cryptography code you're working with is securely designed and side-channel resistant, you can rest assured that hex encoding/decoding won't introduce new vulnerabilities if you use libsodium's implementation.

And if you throw caution to the wind here, you might be fine. None of the researchers I've talked with have alluded to any practical exploits against  cache-timing leaks caused by hex encoding.

Of course, the usual disclaimer applies: Attacks only get better.